# added a picklist on standard account object, now can I bind it to custome object

Tags: custom-object, picklist, standard-objects, dynamic-binding

I have added a picklist, Members,  on standard account object, 
I have created a custom member object now can I bind records of this object to above pick list?

Comment: How do you logically, want to relate these ? In salesforce "bindings" between objects are relationships,  which are  created between objects, not the fields they have. Maybe updating your question with a more detailed explanation will help us understand.

Comment: Thanks ..Ok, let me explain, say I have Continent, Country and States. I need three custom picklist on Account object. I created them now I have to hard code these values but it would be nice to have three different objects Continent, Country and States so as any new continet/country/State gets added it should be avaialbe. I need dependency behavior so I cannot use three look ups as there are no dependent look ups. continet/country/State are example, we similary have Country office, then its branch and then its sub branch which keeps on adding. and account can belong either one of them

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create, and maintain, the picklist separately. There are a few standard picklists (such as Lead Source) that automatically mirror, but this feature cannot be extended to custom fields.

Comment: Please see my commenst above, I have created 3 custom picklist in standard account object which will define the source(HeadOffice, Countryoffice, StateOffice) of the account. I dont want to hardcode values as these offices keeps on adding. But If i create a lookup then it would be hard seraching as I cannot have dependency behavior as in Picklist. This is very common scenario but seems difficult to implement

Answer (score 1):

Next time please edit your question with more info, it'll get updated timestamp = bump to top of the page.

You **can** have dependency in lookups that's similar to dependent picklists - go read about lookup filters. Plus having it in object (=data) and not in picklist (=setup, metadata) means that your power users could maintain the dependencies themselves without asking IT for help every time...

---

But - since your requirement is so specific it's talking about countries and states as picklists - have you seen [the out-of-the-box possibility](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm)? It's a long awaited [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrcnAAC) that was delivered in Winter'14.

[Country and State picklist Implementation PDF Guide](http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf)